# While using openpyxl this execption occurs " TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' "

Tags: python, excel, typeerror, openpyxl

### tl;dr

I want to open/load my excel files with Python for a tool I'm working on. But some of the excel files I have, give this error when I load_workbook with openpyxl. I think this happens because of the amount of drawings and graphs the excel files have and the DrawingML issues openpyxl has.
Does anyone know a way to open/load my excel files, or a workaround by creating a duplicate where all the images and graphs are deleted?

### Background:

In our company we make our calculation reports in Excel. To create a report you have this tedious job to make a table-of-contents by hand. Since I don't want to get into VBA I want to try making this happen in Python. Openpyxl gives me this Exception while trying to load_workbook with openpyxl.

### code:

```
import openpyxl as pyxl
wbook = pyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
```

### Full Exception:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\name\Documents\01_name\06_Programming\Scripts\Inhoudsopgave generator\table_of_content.py", line 36, in <module>
    wbook = pyxl.load_workbook(duplicate, data_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 282, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 257, in read_worksheets
    charts, images = find_images(self.archive, rel.target)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\drawings.py", line 39, in find_images
    cs = get_rel(archive, deps, rel.id, ChartSpace)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\relationship.py", line 168, in get_rel
    obj = cls.from_tree(tree)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\plotarea.py", line 140, in from_tree
    self = super(PlotArea, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  [Previous line repeated 4 more times]
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\geometry.py", line 312, in __init__
    self.w = w
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 67, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'int'>
```

### Possible problem:

Some of these reports contain a lot of text boxes, images, graphs, etc., since it's a full report. I can't seem to load these workbooks, with .xlsx extension, with either openpyxl, xlrd and pylightxl.

### Solutions tried:

I've already found some information regarding this problem. Some mention a DrawingML problem. The advice is to remove all images, but to do so I need to be able to load the workbook first. I also tried downgrading to openpyxl 2.4.11, which didn't work.

### Question(s):

Does anyone think there's a solution to this? I'm also open to different approaches in order to load and read excel files. I was thinking of maybe a way to open and remove all the objects that cause the problem in a duplicate file, and then continuing in the duplicate file to read cells. Any possible solution will be very much appreciated!

Comment: The exception itself is fairly self-explanatory: there is something in the XML (related to drawings, charts, etc.) that does not appear to conform to the OOXML specification. You might want to submit a bug report to openpyxl with a sample file.

Comment: This is a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dervissss, i am one of the maintainers for pylightxl. Could you also submit a issue for it on our github page with an example spreasheet that replicates this issue. I dont believe this should be an issue for pylightxl since it does not work on graphs, textboxes or styles so i am curious as to why you were not able to load it with pylightxl

Comment: Yes, I will try and setup an example this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is not via openpyxl, but via pandas. What I've done is re-write my code to make it work in pandas and iterate through certain specific steps to find chapters in excel. This creates certain problems because any report can be set up differently in Excel (if you even want to write reports in Excel to begin with). The following is what I assume:

1. chapter number is in a different cell than chapter name;
2. chapter name and number are in the same cell;
3. the chapter name and number are found in the first row of a worksheet. If not then on the second, or third, or fourth, or fifth;
4. when a value is found, break loop and go to the next worksheet (assumed next chapter)
5. it is assumed that the paragraphs are found in the same column as the chapter numbers.

A dictionary is made where the chapters are stored as key variables, and the paragraphs are stored as a list in the values variable, corresponding to the right chapter key.

A short example of how this would look like in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df_xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(filePath)

def generate_chapters(df_xlsx):
    global chapPar
    global column
    chapPar = {}
    chaptersOptions = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'H10', 'H11', 'H12', 'H13', 'H14', 'H15', 'H16', 'H17', 'H18', 'H19', 'H20']
    for sheet in df_xlsx.sheet_names:
        if sheet in chaptersOptions:
            for i in range(0, 4):
                dfCol_A = pd.read_excel(df_xlsx, header=None, sheet_name=sheet).iloc[i, 0]
                dfCol_B = pd.read_excel(df_xlsx, header=None, sheet_name=sheet).iloc[i, 1]
                dfCol_C = pd.read_excel(df_xlsx, header=None, sheet_name=sheet).iloc[i, 2]
                dfCol_D = pd.read_excel(df_xlsx, header=None, sheet_name=sheet).iloc[i, 3]
                if (pd.isnull(dfCol_A) != True) and (pd.isnull(dfCol_B) != True) and (pd.isnull(dfCol_C) == True):
                     chapPar.update({str(dfCol_A) + " " + str(dfCol_B):[]})
                     column = 'A'
                     break
```

and so on. After this, a bunch of 'elif' statements follows to cover every option.
The function ends with removing the strings from the chaptersOptions list so it doesn't clash with possible appendices in the excel report.